# How to create csv file using tcl

Tags: tcl

I have two variables, let's say $a with the list name & $b with age, when I try to redirect into csv, it creates csv but both $a & $b are falling into same same row instead of different, How can i separate them into two different rows?

```
    puts $outfile "$b_1 \t$c"
    set outfile [open "result_table_sort.csv" w+]
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way of creating a CSV file is with the [`csv` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/csv/csv.html) in Tcllib. It handles all sorts of tricky edge cases for you so you don't have to.

```
package require csv

set outfile [open "thing.csv" w]
foreach aRow $a bRow $b {
    puts $outfile [csv::join [list $aRow $bRow]]
}
close $outfile
```

You can switch to producing tab-separated output by passing `\t` as the separator character to `csv::join`:

```
    puts $outfile [csv::join [list $aRow $bRow] "\t"]
```

Also consider using the `csv::joinlist` and `csv::joinmatrix` commands. They both let you build an entire table in one go, the first as a list of lists (list of rows, each row containing a list of columns) and the second as a matrix (structure defined in [`struct::matrix` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/struct/matrix.html) in Tcllib).

Comment: without packages?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by putting comma in between two variable solved my issue....

```
    puts $outfile "$b_1,\t$c"
    set outfile [open "result_table_sort.csv" w+]
```